# Нужна помощь в развёртывании DataSnap-приложения

Tags: delphi, sql-server, tcp-ip, роутер

Здравствуйте!

Помогите в развёртывании `DataSnap`-приложения!

C `MSSQL` пока не очень дружусь но из-за проблем хостинга пришлось перейти на `MSSQL`. 
Программа трёхзвенная. Несколько, удалённые друг от друга компьютеры  из своих БД (`Firebird 3`)  данные о товаре, контрагентах,  продаже-покупке и т.д. пересылают на удалённый сервер `MSSQL`. На сервере из этих данных создаются запросы.
Связь с `datasnap`-сервером (сервером приложения) устанавливается через порт `TCP/IP 211`. Для соединения с БД использую компоненты `FireDac` ( `FDConnection`, `FDQuery`).
Порт `MSSQL`-сервера `1450`.

[image: Инфраструктура подключения]
У меня нет опыта создания и развёртивания в сети трёхуровневого приложения, поэтому возникли вопросы и прошу помощи и поправки если неправильно рассуждаю:

**1)** То что связь с сервером приложения устанавливается через порт `TCP/IP 211` это значит, что с сервера приложения к БД и, наоборот, с БД на сервер приложения и с сервера приложения на клиентской программе пакеты тоже будут передаваться через порт `211`?

**2)** Поскольку  `DataSnap`-сервер слушает порт `211` я думаю в маршрутизаторе клиента надо переадресовать внешний `IP` и `211` порт  клиента  на внешний `IP` и `211` порт сервера так:
`222.222.0.1:221` <----> `123.456.78.90:211`. Правильно?

**3)** В маршрутизаторе сервера тоже надо переадресовать внешний IP сервера  на внешний IP клиента:
`123.456.78.90:211` <-----> `222.222.0.1:221`. Правильно?

**4)** На сервере установлен старый сервер `MSSQL 2005`. Чем это ограничивает мой действия?  Могу я на своём домашнем компьютере, где программирую, инсталлировать более новую версию сервера? На этом этапе у меня тоже инсталлирована  `2005` версия и соответственно файл клиента у меня `sqlncli.dll`, но в будущем? Разность версии файла клиента и сервера не создаст проблемы соединения клиента?

**5)** Установил `SSMS 2012`(`sql server management studio`) и в каталоге `system 32` появился файл клиента `sqlncli11.dll`.  т.е. сейчас в `system32`  2 файла клиента: `sqlncli.dll` и `sqlncli11.dll`. Компонент `FDConnection` показывает что для соединения с БД использует файл клиента `sqlncli11.dll` а не `sqlncli.dll`. 2 файла клиента это нормально? Не будет между ними конфликтов? 
Но, с другой стороны, если удалить `SSMS 2012` как тогда визуально связываться с БД?

**6)** `DDNS` и `DataSnap` дружат друг с другом? В смысле избежания динамической IP.
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

1. > связь с сервером приложения устанавливается через порт TCP/IP 211 это значит

Клиенты подключаются к серверу приложений по этому порту (211) и обмениваются с ним информацией. В свою очередь, сервер приложений подключается к БД с другим портом (с тем, которым вы укажите при подключении. Например в FBConnection)

2. > в маршрутизаторе клиента надо переадресовать внешный IP и 211 порт клиента на внешный IP и 211 порт сервера

Скорее всего нет, нужно только на сервере открыть нужный порт (211), но я могу ошибаться.

3. > переадресовать внешный IP сервера на внешный IP клиента

Какая то рекурсия получается с пунктом (2)

4. > Чем это ограничивает мой действия?

Из собственной практики скажу что программа работала как с `MSSQL Server 2005` так и с `MSSQL Server 2008`. Локально был установлен `MSSQL Server 2008`. Для подключения использовал `ADO` компоненты. Трудности начинаются к примеру при миграции данных с сервера на сервер, но все решаемо. У вас же 3-х звенка, изменения разве что будут только на сервере приложений.

Comment: Androschuk с 1 ответом я согласен. Логично рассуждаете- в FDConnection я же указываю порт 1450 которым отправляю запрос на MSSQL. 
 А вот на счёт 2 и 3 пунктов см. что написано на этом линке:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connect_to_DataSnap_Server_(FireDAC)
"The TCP/IP or HTTP port on which the DataSnap server is listening." 
т.е. сервер приложении просто слушает(!) порт 211 то есть открыт и слушает этот порт но разве это значит, что клиент по этому порту отправит запрос?

Comment: Клиент может и по 3000 порту отправить а сервер приложения ждёт пакетов на порт 211. Поэтому и надо переадресовать  в маршрутизаторе клиента. 
Или вы правы и клиент тоже точно по порту 211  достучается до порта 211 сервера приложении? Растерялся уже.

Comment: Androschuk  у компонента TSqlConnection есть свойства HostName, port...  До этого у меня default был выбран localhost. Так что, здесь буду указывать и hostName сервера и порт 211 и никакой переадресации на клиенте не понадобится.
Хотя не понимаю- полученные от сервера пакеты почему окажутся именно в моём компьютере когда в локальной сети у меня есть и другой комп и ноутбук?

Comment: Кто куда смотрип и по какому порту можно посмотреть с помощью спец. утилит (TCPView)[https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx] или (Wireshark)[https://www.wireshark.org/#download]. >Хотя не понимаю- полученные от сервера пакеты почему окажутся именно в моём компьютер. Магия tpc/ip если вы отправили пакет - вы его и получите.